# How to edit GUI designer from java class, since i can't find the ".form" file?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I opened a Form application source in IntelliJ, but i can't find the ".form" file, there are just java class. I want to know whether i could open it's GUI designer, and how?

Comment: You really needed to capture your entire screen? Have you never heard of a clipping tool that crops an image to the relevant content? What would you expect mobile users to do with that large image? How do you read that on a phone screen or tablet? And what about what it does to data and costs?  And then you did it **again**? Please see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) - it discusses images of code, but many of the reasons apply to other posts as well. Images should only be used when absolutely necessary to demonstrate a problem, and then smallest as possible.

Comment: Ok, I got it,  I didn't realise it, Thank you foy your lesson!

Answer (score 1):

> but i can't find the ".form" file, there are just java class

You need to learn how to create GUIs, without the 'GUI designer' of an IDE. That's right, you'll need to actually learn Java. (Shock, horror.) GUI designers work better once you can code a GUI in pure Java, in any case.

> I want to know whether i could open it's GUI designer,as figure 2, ..?

No. Most Java code for GUIs **don't have** an associated `.form` file.